# destroying and recreating a joint in the tick method

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d, box2d-iphone

I have created a weldJoint and destroyed it (please see update method in the code below). On destroying the weldJoint I set the linear velocity to make one body towards another body creating another weldJoint. The weldJoint never gets recreated. I am sure it is because of the following lines:

```
if (weldJoint == NULL) return;

world->DestroyJoint(weldJoint);
weldJoint = NULL;
```

in the code. Because it's already NULL during the next timestep it doesn't create the weldJoint. At first I tried using break statement after destroying the joint but I was getting an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error pointing to the line:

```
world->DestroyJoint(weldJoint);
```

How can I create destroy and recreate the weldJoints?

update method:

```
-(void) update: (ccTime) dt
{

int32 velocityIterations = 8;
int32 positionIterations = 1;

// Instruct the world to perform a single step of simulation. It is
// generally best to keep the time step and iterations fixed.
world->Step(dt, velocityIterations, positionIterations);

// using the iterator pos over the set
std::set<BodyPair *>::iterator pos;

for(pos = bodiesForJoints.begin(); pos != bodiesForJoints.end(); ++pos)
{

b2WeldJointDef weldJointDef;

BodyPair *bodyPair = *pos;
b2Body *bodyA = bodyPair->bodyA;
b2Body *bodyB = bodyPair->bodyB;

weldJointDef.Initialize(bodyA, bodyB, bodyA->GetWorldCenter());

weldJointDef.collideConnected = false;
weldJoint = (b2WeldJoint*) world->CreateJoint(&weldJointDef);

// Free the structure we allocated earlier.
free(bodyPair);

// Remove the entry from the set.
bodiesForJoints.erase(pos);
}

for(b2Body *b = world->GetBodyList(); b; b=b->GetNext())    {
if (b->GetUserData() != NULL)
{
    CCSprite *mainSprite = (CCSprite*)b->GetUserData();
    if (mainSprite.tag == 1) {
        mainSprite.position = CGPointMake( b->GetPosition().x * PTM_RATIO, b->GetPosition().y * PTM_RATIO);
        CGPoint mainSpritePosition = mainSprite.position;
        if (mainSprite.isMoved) {

                    if (weldJoint == NULL) return; 

                    world->DestroyJoint(weldJoint);
                    weldJoint = NULL;

                    b2Vec2 velocity = b2Vec2(3.5, 2.2);
                    b->SetLinearVelocity(velocity);  


                }
        }
    }
}

}
```

Comment: I don't see those lines you mention in the update method...

Comment: @iforce2d: sorry about that, I just corrected it. Thanks.